# Wait for keypress in a loop VB.NET WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keypress

I'm making a winforms application, whose purpose is to write [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) symbols to a textbox using key combinations. The user presses keys while focused on a RichTextBox. Some key-combinations, such as Ctrl + S, will simply produce a character and wait for the next keypress, such as `ʃ`. Other key combinations will produce a different character when you repeatedly press the same key while holding Ctrl. For example, if I press Ctrl then A, `æ` will be typed, but if I press A again while still holding Ctrl, `æ` will be deleted and `ɑ` will appear instead. It will keep cycling through these two keys until the player releases Ctrl or presses a different key.

I'm stuck trying to implement this behaviour, though. This is a rough idea of what I've got so far; the main stumbling block is that I don't know how to pause in the middle of a loop and read a keypress, using Forms:

```
Private Sub IPAtext_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles IPAtext.KeyDown
    Dim AChars() As Char = {"æ", "ɑ"}
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0
    Select Case e.Modifiers
        Case Keys.Control
            Select Case e.KeyCode
                Case Keys.A
                    While e.Modifiers = Keys.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.A
                        IPAtext.AppendText(AChars(Counter))
                        '-- Pause for keypress. If keypress =/= A then complete loop, if keypress is A again then increase counter. --
                        Counter = (Counter + 1) Mod AChars.Count 'Increments the counter so that it cycles back to 0 when it goes past the count of AChars.
                        '-- Only execute the line below if keypress is A. --
                        IPAtext.Text = IPAtext.Text.Remove(IPAtext.TextLength - 1) 'Remove the last character from the textbox.
                    End While
            End Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

I should also note that I'm trying to simulate to an extent the behaviour of [this IPA web app](http://ipa.typeit.org/).

Comment: You have much bigger problems, Ctrl+A already does something in a RichTextBox, it selects all text.  Clearly not what you want, not simple to fix.  You cannot "pause in the middle", you need to use a variable.

Comment: Point taken. I was going to figure that bit when I came to it, but perhaps I should forward-think a bit more. Anyway, what type of variable? I know in Console there's ConsoleKeyInfo and ConsoleKey but I don't know my way so comfortably around Forms. And what function could I use to read a keypress and insert it into that variable?

Comment: You might have to use ProcessCmdKey  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscs73zz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with when I tried this. Set a handler on the KeyDown event and then supress all KeyPresses by default. Then see if you can match the current keyCode to a Case you expect to be special. Otherwise unsupress the KeyEventArgs object and leave the Sub.

My code will select text that you expect to loop, thus you can manually select a char and "continue" looping even if Ctrl was released. You will have to modify this to your own liking, but this is atleast a start for you.

```
   Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    e.Handled = True

    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.A And e.Modifiers = Keys.Control
            RichTextBox1.SelectedText = GetCharacterToPrint(RichTextBox1.SelectedText, New Char() {"æ", "ɑ"})
            RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart - 1, 1)
        Case Else
            e.Handled = False
            e.SuppressKeyPress = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Here is a short function for returning the next character:

```
Private Function GetCharacterToPrint(ByVal SelectedText As String, ByVal Characters As Char()) As Char
    If SelectedText.Length <> 1 Then
        Return Characters(0)
    End If
    Dim c As Char = SelectedText(0)
    Dim index As Integer = String.Join("", Characters).IndexOf(c)
    If index = Characters.Length - 1 Then
        Return Characters(0)
    Else
        Return Characters(index + 1)
    End If
End Function
```

And finally how to continue on after ControlKey is released:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.ControlKey Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this isn't enough to solve the problem. It only works when selecting text that is already written, when I want Ctrl + A to *generate* the text and then change it if the user presses Ctrl + A again - furthermore, it needs to cycle between all possible variants for that key combination until the user releases Ctrl or presses another key. I still don't understand how I can do this.

Comment: If nothing is selected or if the selected text is not "æ" it will Print æ, if æ is Selected it will print "Æ". SelectedText is simply the CaretPosition. Or are you perhaps coding in .NET4.5? This is done in 4.0.

Comment: I'm on VS2012 Express, using .NET 4.5.50938 (how absurdly specific). Would that make a difference?

Comment: I guess so since it is not working for you as it does for me. Sadly I do not have 4.5 available, so someone else would have to modify this to work in 4.5. I'll have a look at the cycling in the meantime.

Comment: This is all I can do for you I am afraid. Hope you get it to work.

Comment: Thanks :). I should probably get some work done, but I'll try this in a bit and let you know.